# Only show item one at a time with skip

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is, only show one task at a time..If the user clicks on skip, show the next one... It could be a list of 3 tasks to a list of 30 tasks.

So how do show one at a time?

```
$("a#skip").click(function() {
    $('#id_task_{{i.id}}').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400);
}; 

<div id="reload">
    <div class="task" id="id_task_1">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 1
        </a>
        <a class="skip_class" id="skip">Skip</a>
    </div>
    <div class="task" id="id_task_2">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 2
        </a>
        <a class="skip_class" id="skip">Skip</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rGvna/12/) to get an idea with what I'm working with. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ID` is supposed to be unique on the page...

Comment: @Sushanth-- they are unique when rendering the list on my local. it still doesn't work. But I'll fix, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Also you have a syntax error.. Not closing the event function properly.. Supposed to end with `});` .. And the effect you are trying to do requires the `jQuery` effects core plugin to get it working

Comment: Check this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rGvna/11/

Comment: @Sushanth-- Thank you, very much appreciated.. But I'm still trying to just show one one task at a time. So when the user clicks skip, the current slides over and shows the next.

Comment: You can skip the `id="skip"`on the `skip_class`-links :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
// Add a class called hide to all the div with class task to hide it on page load

$(".skip_class").click(function () {
    var $currTask = $(this).closest('.task');
    // Show the next task
    $currTask.nextAll('.task').first().removeClass('hide');
    // Hide the current task
    $currTask.hide('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 400);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rGvna/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all but the first task with css and show em on click:

```
.task {
   display: none;   
}
#reload .task:first-child {
   display: block;   
}
```

...

```
$("a.skip_class").click(function() {
   var task = $(this).parent();
   task.hide();
   task.next().show();
   if(task.next().attr('id') === undefined) {
     task.parent().children('.task:first').show();   
)};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fAszU/1/

And as @Sushanth mentioned you need the jQuery effects core plugin for the slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

A working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rGvna/14/

I would suggest using a data attribute on your .task elements that contains corresponding page number.

```
<div id="reload">
    <div class="task" data-task-num="1">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 1
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="task" data-task-num="2">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 2
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="task" data-task-num="3">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 3
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="task" data-task-num="4">
        <a href="link to task" class="image">
            Task 4
        </a>
    </div>    
</div>
<a class="skip_class" id="skip">Skip</a>
```

And then use jQuery show(), hide() methods to cycle through the tasks as follow:

```
var starting_task = 1;
var last_task  = 4;
var skip_to_task = function(task_num) {
        $('.task').hide();
        $('.task[data-task-num=' + task_num +']').show();
        if (task_num < last_task) {
            $("#skip").data('target-task', task_num + 1);    
        }
    };

skip_to_task(starting_task); // go to first task by default

$("#skip").click(function(e) {
    var target_task = $(e.target).data('target-task');
    skip_to_task(target_task);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.skip_class").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next('.task').show();
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rGvna/17/

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your post and realized you needed to not only hide teh skipped task but only show 1 task at a time.

Edited my post / code accordingly